# show that a sequence is superadditive

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, contest-math

> A nondecreasing sequence $s_0, s_1,\cdots$ of nonnegative integers is superadditive if $s_{i+j} \ge s_i+s_j$ for all nonnegative integers $i,j.$ Suppose $\{s_n\}$ and $\{t_n\}$ are two superadditive sequences, and let $\{u_n\}$ be the nondecreasing sequence with the property that each integer appears in $\{u_n\}$ exactly as many times in $\{s_n\}$ and $\{t_n\}$ combined. Show that $\{u_n\}$ is also superadditive.

For a nondecreasing sequence $\{a_n\}$ of nonnegative integers, define $S_a(n)$ to be the smallest index $k$ so that $a_k\ge n$. Define a sequence $\{s_n\}$ to be subadditive if $s_{i+j} \leq s_i + s_j$ for all nonnegative $i,j$. In general, $S_u(n) = S_s(n)+ S_t(n)$ (that's because $S_u(n)$ is precisely the number of integers smaller than $n$ in the sequences $\{s_n\}$ and $\{t_n\}$ and the latter number is precisely $S_s(n)+ S_t(n)$). So if $S_s$ and $S_t$ are subadditive then so is $S_u$. Also note that $S_a$ is subadditive iff $a$ is superadditive. Indeed, suppose $\{a_n\}$ is superadditive. Then for any nonnegative $i,j,a_{S_a(i) + S_a(j)} \ge a_{S_a(i)} + a_{S_a(j)} \ge i+ j ,$ so $S_{i+j} \leq S_i + S_j$. Now suppose $\{S_a\}$ is subadditive. We can obtain the sequence $a$ from $S_a$ as follows. First find the first j so that $S_a(j) > 0.$ Then $a_0 = j - 1.$ In general, to find $a_i,$ find the smallest $j$ so that $i < S_a(j)$. Then $a_{i} = j-1$. Indeed, by the definition of $j,$ we have $S_a(j-1) \leq i$. So the smallest index $k$ so that $a_k\ge j - 1$ is at most i, implying that $a_i\ge j-1$ as $\{a_n\}$ is nondecreasing. Also, $S_a(j) > i$, implying that $a_i < j$, and hence the result. We need to show that $a$ is superadditive. Let $i,j\ge 0$ be indices. Then from above, $a_i = i_2 - 1, a_j = j_2 - 1,$ where $i_2$ is the smallest index so that $S_a(i_2) > i$ and $j_2$ is the smallest index so that $S_a(j_2) > j$. Also from above, $a_{i+j} = t_2 - 1,$ where  $t_2$ is the smallest index so that $S_a(t_2) > i + j$. We need to show $t_2 - 1 \ge i_2 - 1 + j_2 - 1$. Suppose for a contradiction that $t_2 < i_2 + j_2 - 1$. Recall that $S_a(i_2)$ is the number of integers in the sequence $a$ less than $i_2$. So there are at least $i+1$ such integers. Similarly, there are at least $j+1$ integers less than $j_2$ and $i+j+1$ integers less than $t_2$. Note that $S_a$ is nondecreasing. Indeed, suppose there exist $i\leq j$ with $S_a(i) > S_a(j)$. Then $a_{S_a(j)}\ge j$ and $a_{S_a(j)} < i$ so $j < i$, a contradiction. By subadditivity, $S_a(i_2 - 1 + j_2 - 1) \leq S_a(i_2 - 1) + S_a(j_2 - 1) \leq i + j < S_a(t_2)$. Hence we must have $t_2 > i_2 - 1 + j_2 - 1$, and thus the result follows.

Assuming the above holds, we just need to show that $S_u(n)$ is subadditive, which follows immediately as both $S_s(n)$ and $S_t(n)$ are subadditive and $S_u(n) = S_s(n) + S_t(n)$ for all n.

> Have I made any mistakes?